# Exchange distribution group EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to create an universal distribution groups for exchange in my c# app.

I'm use this code but it creates only private group for a specific account. (using EWS)

```
EWService = new ExchangeService();
EWService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(SA_mail, SA_password);
EWService.AutodiscoverUrl(SA_mail);
ContactGroup contactGroup = new ContactGroup(EWService);
contactGroup.DisplayName = "GRP_DIF_" + textBox1.Text;
contactGroup.Save();
```

How can I create universal distribution group which is recognized by exchange ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can create a contact group, which is a private distribution group,
>   by using the EWS Managed API or EWS. To create contact groups, use the
>   methods in the ContactGroup EWS Managed API class, or use the
>   CreateItem EWS operation.
>
> **Note that you can’t use the EWS Managed API or EWS to create a
>   universal distribution group or security group. To create a universal
>   distribution group or security group, you can use the
>   [New-DistributionGroupExchange Management Shell cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998856(v=exchg.150).aspx).**

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn629394(v=exchg.150).aspx

If you need to invoke that PowerShell commandlet from within your C# Application, [the best way to start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd182449(v=vs.85).aspx) is to use the `System.Management.Automation` namespace.

Comment: Which wayis the best  to use cmdlet in my C# app ?

Comment: the idea is not to use it in your c# app. EWS should not be used for things like that.
Create a PowerShell script. If needed you can compile your C# app to a library (.dll) and use that in your PowerShell script.

Comment: This is a little part of my project I have to find a way to integrate the group creation to this app. No way ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793868/programmatically-create-a-distribution-group-in-active-directory
this question shows you how to use it in your c# application, but it's rather complicated, why don't you just create a powershell script?

Comment: Because I have a "fat" graphical interface for managing users/managers/admin etc.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd182449(v=vs.85).aspx
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/